# How to implement face recognition with accord.net?

Tags: c#, .net, svm, face-recognition, accord.net

I currently have zero experience with ml and deep learning, and I just recently found out about accord.net. And I want to implement recognition using accord.net and svm, can anyone put me through how to do this or recommend some resource to guide me from scratch

Comment: Have you seen this link:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49243301/using-an-accord-net-svm-for-face-recognition-multiclasssupportvectormachine

Comment: @Mahsa thanks, i'll check it out